# HAML: do I need to h escape output for 2.3.x pages or does HAML take care of that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, haml, csrf

Rails 3 takes care of it, but what about rails 2.3.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will have to do this manually with

```
= h "my unsafe string"
```

or with

```
= sanitize "my unsafe string"
```

Alternatively, you can set the :escape_html option to true, then you will only have to do

```
= "my unsafe string"
```